# iOS: connectionDidFinishLoading

Tags: ios, xcode4, ios4

I need some help. I am calling the login function from another class,

```
// Login on server
- (BOOL) login:(NSString*) username password:(NSString*)password
{
  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:subscribedAppsURL]];
  NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
  [connectionDict setObject:connection forKey:@"login"];
  [connection release];
  return true;
}

// delegate
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{
  NSLog(@"Finished Loading");

    if (connection == [connectionDict objectForKey:@"login"]) {
    [connection release];
    //@TODO Here I want to function login to return true.
  }

}
```

At the end of connectionDidFinishLoading I want to return the TRUE/ FALSE value in the function login. Does anyone have some suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send your request synchronously like this:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:subscribedAppsURL]];
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

if (error != nil)
{
    NSString *stringResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Reponse:%@", response);

    //Handle the response, possible just return true here:
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error:%@", error.localizedDescription);
}
```

---

With the intent of using delegates:

```
//In Header
@protocol LoginCompletionDelegate
-(void) didCompleteAndIsLoggedIn:(BOOL) loggedIn;
@end

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<LoginCompletionDelegate> delegate;


//In implementation
- (BOOL) loginWithDelegate:(id<LoginCompletionDelegate>)target username:(NSString*) username password:(NSString*)password
{
   delegate = target;
  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:subscribedAppsURL]];
  NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
  [connectionDict setObject:connection forKey:@"login"];
  [connection release];
  return true;
}

// delegate
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{
  NSLog(@"Finished Loading");

    if (connection == [connectionDict objectForKey:@"login"]) {
    [connection release];
    //@TODO Here I want to function login to return true.
    [delegate didCompleteAndIsLoggedIn:YES];
  }

}

//There is another method that looks like this. I might have the signature a bit wrong
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection*) connection didFailWithError:(NSError*) error
{
    [delegate didCompleteAndIsLoggedIn:NO];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is this good practice? Or do I need to use NSNotifications or something?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, I'm using that method exactly as it should be used. But be aware that it can be very slow and the calling thread will be blocked while it runs. You shouldn't call this on your main thread.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I'd rather do it the way with delegates. If it does not work I'll have your back up, thanks.

Comment: I've posted a solution with delegates too

Comment: Cool, I am making some progress. In the arguments of loginWithDelegate there is: (id<LoginCompletionDelegate>)target   ..If I call this function where do I get this target? I am now in the process of finding materials about protocols and delegates.

Comment: Your target will likely be the `self` of the calling class. You then make your calling class implement the protocol:
`@class ClassThatIsCallingLogin : NSObject <LoginCompletionDelegate>`

Comment: This did the trick!! Thanks.

And don't forget the @synthesize delegate.